# ¿Que consecuencias para la accesibilidad traen los elementos que generan un esquema ajeno al del documento web?

Tags: html5

MDN dice:

> Existen elementos, cuyo propósito habitual es introducir contenido
>   externo a la página: , , ,  y
>   .  Estos elementos no se "montan" sobre el esquema global, sin
>   importar su contenido, lo que conlleva un desacoplo o aislamiento
>   entre las partes

Lo que entiendo de esta afirmación es que un elemento como blockquote no formaría parte de la jerarquía de temas del documento.

por ejemplo:

```
<body>
  <h1>Titulo principal</h1>

  <section>
       <h2>Subtitulo</h2>
       <p>Parrafo</p>
       <blockquote>
            <p>Cita</p>
       </blockquote>
  </section>
</body>
```

Esto generaría la siguiente jerarquía temática en el documento:

- Titulo Principal

  - Subtitulo

Entonces según este ejemplo que puse para plantear mi duda y el que esta acá:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document#Definiendo_secciones_en_HTML5

`blockquote` técnicamente no formaría parte del documento no compondría la estructura, se trataría como otro documento.

- ¿En cuestiones de accesibilidad que consecuencias tiene esto, el que
  elementos como `blockquote` no estén en la jerarquía de contenido?
- ¿Al momento de presentar a los usuarios el documento, `blockquote` como
  se les presentaría? ¿Como una subseccion del section con la cabecera    subtitulo?

Answer (score 0):

Según la especificación 'html5' para 'blockquotes', el marcado correcto en esta situación sería usar 'figure' para agrupar la cita y el autor (si lo necesitases), dejando fuera el resto de elementos. Copio:

> ... un elemento blockquote se utiliza junto con un elemento figura y
>   su figcaption para relacionar claramente una cita con su atribución
>   (que no es parte de la cita y, por lo tanto, no pertenece al
>   bloquequote)

Tal es así que si tu código queda del siguiente modo cumplirá todas las especificaciones necesarias y por tanto con la accesibilidad:

```html
  <body>
  <h1>Titulo principal</h1>

  <section>
       <h2>Subtitulo</h2>
       <p>Parrafo</p>
    <figure>       
       <blockquote>
            <p>Cita</p>
       </blockquote>
       <figcaption>Autor de la cita</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
</body>
```

Dejo un enlace a la documentación por que te comentaba por si te resultase de ayuda con tu pregunta: [The blockquote element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element)